# smbclient does not open terminal when connecting to Samba server

Tags: samba, docker, smb

I set up a Samba server in an Ubuntu Docker container following [these instructions](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#1-overview) from Ubuntu.com. I added a user with commands (as root):

```
adduser sambauser
smbpasswd -a sambauser
mkdir /home/sambauser/sambashare
chown sambauser /home/sambauser/sambashare
chgrp sambauser /home/sambauser/sambashare
```

Then I added a share by appending the following to the end of /etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
[sambashare1]
    comment = first test on Ubuntu
    path = /home/sambauser/sambashare
    read only = no
    browsable = yes
    valid users = sambauser
```

Then restarted the samba service:

```
service smbd restart
service nmbd restart
```

But when I attempt to connect with smbclient:

```
smbclient -L localhost -U sambauser
```

I get the error:

```
SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available
```

Following advice from [another AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265923/configuring-20-04-samba-for-smbv1), I lowered the minimum protocol accepted by the server by adding the following lines to /etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
client min protocol = NT1
server min protocol = NT1
```

This gives the message "Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing." and displays this:

```
[printers]
        Server               Comment
        ---------            -------

        Workgroup            Master
        ---------            ------
        WORKGROUP            7A7464B81779
```

But still doesn't open an interactive console to access the samba server like I expect it to. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Interactive console? You are issuing the wrong command for that. You want: `smbclient //localhost/sambashare1 -U sambauser` You should end up with a `smb: \>` prompt.

Comment: @Morbius1 This worked! You would not believe how much time I spent troubleshooting this. I really appreciate your help!