# Sonos music library on 22.04

Tags: samba, music

I have been sharing a music directory through Samba on several versions of Ubuntu, going back at least to 18.04, perhaps further, and before that on numerous releases of Red Hat. I use this shared directory for the music library on Sonos.

This has all worked flawlessly, until I upgraded to 22.04, and then the share was no longer available to Sonos, although it is still accessible through Windows explorer on a Windows 10 computer. I have been using the same smb.conf all along, and there were no changes made during the upgrade to 22.04.

I am using the older Sonos technology, which requires SMBv1, and I have verified that NT1 is available using nmap.

To eliminate the possibility that the issue is some change in the Sonos software, I set up a machine running Ubuntu 18.04, using the same Samba configuration, and verified that I can access the music library on the 18.04 server.

I have searched for any information about changes to Samba in the 22.04 release, but have found nothing.

I have tried to access a music library hosted on two different devices running 22.04, which have been set up independently, and Sonos cannot access the share on either machine, while the shares are readily available and browseable through Windows Explorer on a Windows 10 laptop.

I am curious to know if there is a known issue with the Samba implementation in 22.04 that would interfere with implementation of Sonos shared music libraries hosted on 22.04.

The answer suggested by Mikewhatever does not fix this problem.  I had found that suggestion previously when trying to fix the problem, but I have had that line in my smb.conf all along, which is why things worked through 20.04.  It broke with 22.04.

```
    #======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]

   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server min protocol = NT1
;  server max protocol = NT1
   ntlm auth = yes
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

   dns proxy = no

   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000

   syslog = 0
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

   server role = standalone server
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no

[files]
comment = Read/Write file share
path = /storage
guest ok = yes
writeable = yes
create mask = 0777

[music]
comment = Read Only music share
path = /storage/music
guest ok = yes
writeable = no
browseable = yes
create mask = 0777
```

Comment: Please, post your samba/cifs smb.conf file. Also do `ls -hal` on your shared folder. Verify owner and acls.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configuring 20.04 samba for SMBv1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265923/configuring-20-04-samba-for-smbv1)

Comment: @jwk Paste the file into your question as an edit.

Comment: @TimChaubet this should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: For those interested in running Sonos S1 with SMB/CIFS and have trouble getting it to work on Samba, take a look at this new [SMB server made specially for Sonos S1](https://barrydegraaff.nl/sonossmb/).