# Connecting to SMB 1.0 File Share

Tags: networking, mount, samba, cifs

Running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

After this mornings update, I can no longer connect to an SMB 1.0 server (server is running Samba 3.4.7 on Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS).

The update was from `Samba 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.2` to `Samba 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.3`.
For such a small update, I didn't see anything in the changelog that would eliminate SMB 1.0 support but keep getting the following error:

```
CIFS: VFS: Use of the less secure dialect vers=1.0 is not recommended unless required for access to very old servers
CIFS: Attempting to mount \\192.168.1.151\import
CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -5
```

Servers I have running the slightly older 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.2 version still can connect to these shares.

Any thoughts would be appreciated. At the moment, I am not sure what options I have to get the older Ubuntu box updated to something more recent that can support something newer than version 1.0 (it is a vendor supplied "appliance" so my options are very limited).

Comment: Have you tried setting the `client min protocol` as described here [Configuring 20.04 samba for SMBv1](https://askubuntu.com/a/1265990/178692) ?

Comment: mount.cifs is not controlled by samba on the client. It doesn't even know smb.conf exists. It's controlled by the Linux kernel directly. Did you also update the kernel in 22.04? If so to what level?